# Alternatives to jQuery Mobile animations

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm currently using Phonegap to make an app with jQuery Mobile and as such the use of the `.fadein() .fadeout(), .hide()` and `show()` functions don't work as well as I have hoped are there any alternatives to these functions? I've been reading up on using `CSS3` is better for animations as its hardware accelerated but I write this post in hope that there is perhaps a better way of achieving animations on `Phonegap` or is `CSS3` the best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Steroids.js which bridges The Performance Gap Between PhoneGap And Native Apps By Using Native UI Components And Animations

Check the following documentations to get started

http://techcrunch.com/2013/08/20/steroids-js-bridges-the-performance-gap-between-phonegap-and-native-apps-by-using-native-ui-components-and-animations/

http://www.marketwire.com/press-release/appgyver-steroidsjs-closes-the-performance-gap-between-html5-and-native-apps-1823040.htm

Answer (score 2):

JS animations are slow, for a multiplatform app (web mobile, android, iphone) I would look into CSS 3D transitions. CSS 3D transitions are hardware accelerated, and you can do preatty neat stuff.

Heres an example:
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2013/03/15/animating-lists-with-css-3-transitions/